# simplexml_load_string not displaying all contents inside of its element (PHP and XML)

Tags: php, xml, laravel, simplexml

I can't get the whole data from XML when transforming it using simplexml_load_string

Example: partial data of XML

```
<variable ident="592952" type="single" cint:sort-order="1"
cint:hide-on="Registration"
cint:country-language-question-id="2222">
```

When i used simplexml_load_string and wrap them at json_encode and json_decode to become array, it will look like this:

```
+"variable": SimpleXMLElement {#550 ▼
            +"@attributes": array:2 [▼
              "ident" => "782752"
              "type" => "single"
            ]
```

Question: How can i get the value of `cint:sort-order="1"` from the variable element in XML form and put it together with some variables and to look like this? Is this possible?

```
"variable": SimpleXMLElement {#550 ▼
                +"@attributes": array:2 [▼
                  "ident" => "782752"
                  "type" => "single",
                  "cint:sort-order" =>"1",
                  "cint:hide-on" =>"Registration",
                  "cint:country-language-question-id" =>"2222"
                ]
```

Comment: A `SimpleXMLElement` has a function `attributes`, which you can look through to get `cint:sort-order` and others, with their respective values.

Comment: did wrapping simplexml_load_string into json_encode and wrap it again with json_decode to make them arrays will remove the attributes function?

Comment: That, I don't know. But you can still test ;) and if so, do all your processing before json_decode'ing them.

Comment: With SimpleXMLElement - `attributes()` will only return the values from the default namespace, you will have to use `attributes('cint', true)` to get them from he `cint` namespace.

Comment: Hi Nigel.. you made my life easy thanks that I was looking. adding
->attributes('cint', true) attributes from element that has cint attribs. Thank you also Julien :) this xml is a  bit of pain hahahaha thank you both of u :)